# How to fix ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)?

Tags: python, pytorch

Recently faced with such a problem: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).

```
import os
import natsort
from PIL import Image
import torchvision
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import transforms, models
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
```

```
root_dir = './images/'
```

```
class Col(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, main_dir, transform):
        self.main_dir = main_dir
        self.transform = transform
        all_images = self.all_img(main_dir = main_dir)
        self.total_imges = natsort.natsorted(all_images)
 
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.total_imges)
 
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_loc = os.path.join(self.total_imges[idx])
        image = Image.open(img_loc).convert("RGB")
        tensor_image = self.transform(image)
        return tensor_image
 
    def all_img(self, main_dir):
        img = []     
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(main_dir):
            for name in files:
                img.append(os.path.join(path, name))
        return img
```

```
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=False)
model.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, 256),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Dropout(p=0.3),
                         nn.Linear(256, 100),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Dropout(p=0.4),
                         nn.Linear(100,9))
# model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model.pth'))
```

```
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if("bn" not in name):
        param.requires_grad = False
```

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5457, 0.5457, 0.5457], std=[0.2342, 0.2342, 0.2342])    
])
 
data = Col(main_dir=root_dir, transform=transform)
 
dataset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=130)
 
train_set, validate_set= torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [round(len(dataset)*0.7), (len(dataset) - round(len(dataset)*0.7))])
```

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda") 
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
 
model.to(device)
```

```
def train(model, optimizer, loss_fn, train_set, validate_set, epochs=20, device="cpu"):
    for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
        training_loss = 0.0
        valid_loss = 0.0
        model.train()
        for batch in train_set:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            inputs, targets = batch
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            targets = targets.to(device)
            output = model(inputs)
            loss = loss_fn(output, targets)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            training_loss += loss.data.item() * inputs.size(0)
        training_loss /= len(train_set.dataset)
 
        model.eval()
        num_correct = 0 
        num_examples = 0
        for batch in validate_set:
            inputs, targets = batch
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            output = model(inputs)
            targets = targets.to(device)
            loss = loss_fn(output,targets) 
            valid_loss += loss.data.item() * inputs.size(0)
            correct = torch.eq(torch.max(F.softmax(output, dim=1), dim=1)[1], targets)
            num_correct += torch.sum(correct).item()
            num_examples += correct.shape[0]
        valid_loss /= len(validate_set.dataset)
 
        print('Epoch: {}, Training Loss: {:.2f}, Validation Loss: {:.2f}, accuracy = {:.2f}'.format(epoch, training_loss,
        valid_loss, num_correct / num_examples))
 
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
```

But the call to this function

```
train(model, optimizer,torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(), train_set.dataset, validate_set.dataset, epochs=100, device=device)
```

gives this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_4828/634509595.py in <module>
----> 1 train(model, optimizer,torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(), train_set.dataset, validate_set.dataset, epochs=100, device=device)
 
/tmp/ipykernel_4828/1473922939.py in train(model, optimizer, loss_fn, train_set, validate_set, epochs, device)
      6         for batch in train_set:
      7             optimizer.zero_grad()
----> 8             inputs, targets = batch
      9             inputs = inputs.to(device)
     10             targets = targets.to(device)
 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch doesn't contain both the inputs and the targets. Your problem is just that **getitem** returns only tensor_image (which is presumably the inputs) and not whatever targets should be.

This means that the code:

```
inputs, targets = batch
```

must become:

```
inputs = batch
```

since there is just one return variable (`return tensor_image`) in each `batch` of the `train_set`.